# mysql server has gone away in result of storing API response in php

Tags: php, mysql

i am experiencing mysql server has gone away in response of storing API result in mysql database through php code is follow,

```
$api_response = sendmsg($group_detail['cell_no'], $SMS); //function to execute API

    //update sms sent record
$sql = "INSERT INTO sms_sent_record (record_id, api_response) 
                         VALUES (NULL, '$api_response')";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error, updating sms & group count               
              in sms_sent_count failed : ' . mysql_error());
```

i have tried many other options such as storing api response in array and then store it in mysql table, but in any way it throws the same error. The other code in function after this error  will not executed by server.

i think it is due to delay in api response and timeout problem in mysql.

Is there any way to avoid this error and storing result in proper way.

Comment: "The MYSQL server has gone away" is an actual error. The most unhelpful one possible but an error none the less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work if you omit the sendmsg and do:

```
$api_response = 'test';//sendmsg($group_detail['cell_no'], $SMS); //function to execute API
```

If so, does sendmsg() use some sort of mysql connection at any time?
If it does, you may want to store the link from when you connected to the database the first time and reuse it.

```
$link=mysql_connect();
..
..
mysql_query($sql,$link);
```

Comment: it works. But sql records only first two response... rest of the code does not run at all.

Comment: What does the $api_response typically look like? -You may want to escape it also using '$api_response=mysql_real_escape_string($api_response);'

Answer (score 0):

[There are lots of reasons for the gone away message](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html) but I suspect your problem is that you open the connection to your DB before the API call (to send an SMS ?) and the API call causes the server to terminal your connection before the `INSERT` is run

Try moving your open db connection to just before the `INSERT` statement :

```
$api_response = sendmsg($group_detail['cell_no'], $SMS); //function to execute API
// open connection here
$sql = "INSERT INTO sms_sent_record (record_id, api_response) 
                         VALUES (NULL, '$api_response')";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error, updating sms & group count               
              in sms_sent_count failed : ' . mysql_error());
```

Check your value set for [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) this is

> The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a
>   noninteractive connection before closing it.

If you have this value set very low the server will timeout your connection between opening your connection and running your query.